# Generic Repository GetAll Filter Does not filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I have a generic method that is supposed to return a IEnumerable of anything. In addition, the user has the option to filter out the return list. The issue I am having is that the list is not being filtering. For example, I am trying to get a list of users from the database; I calling the method using this syntax

```
var users = unit.UserRepository.GetAll(x => x.UserName == username);
```

I was expected one users, but it returns all the users in the database.

Here is my generic method:

```
 public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter =null, 
             Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderby = null, string property = "")
         {
             IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
             if (filter != null)
             {
                 query.Where(filter);
             }

             if (property != null)
             {
                 foreach (var p in property.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                 {
                     query = query.Include(p);
                 }
             }

             if(orderby != null)
             {
                 return orderby(query);
             }  else
             {
                   return query.ToList();
             }
         }
```

IS there something that I am missing here?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the `GetAll` function, are you sure there is data in the db that matches the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reassigning the value of `query` after you apply the filter:

```
if (filter != null)
{
    query.Where(filter);
}
```

Should be:

```
if (filter != null)
{
    query = query.Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: thank you. I did not notice it, and I've been looking at the code since last night.

Comment: @JosianeFerice Not a problem.  Been there myself many times. :)